# iOS - Provisioning portal Tabs on right hand side are not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios5

Right Hand Side tabs for the Provisioning Portal are not found:

Hi, I am new to iPhone and iPad development.  When I log in with my Apple ID I can not find    the Provisioning Portal tabs.  Is the provisioning portal available only for paid users?  If I am a free user, can I see the Provisioning Portal?  I cannot find it, what steps do I have to take for creating Provisioning Profiles?  I am trying to set up an app for push notifications.

My thinking is,

> i. if Provisioning Portal is showing for only paid user?
>
> ii. if I am a free user, how can I access the Provisioning Portal?

Please suggest your answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is only available to paid users

Answer (score 2):

You can't access provisioning portal with free apple id you need to paid ios developer account .

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to the `iOS Provisioning Portal` if you're not enrolled in the [`Apple iOS Developer Program`](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).